# Invalid argument (internal Keystore code: -38 message: In KeystoreOperation::finish

Tags: java, android, encryption, keystore

I am writing an android application, where i want to save some files crypted.
Most files work properly while writing and reading. When i try to read larger strings, that have been written crypted into files, i get the following exception while decrypting them:
`Invalid argument (internal Keystore code: -38 message: In KeystoreOperation::finish`

Does anybody have an idea, why that does not work or what i am doing wrong?

Heres my code:

```
public byte[] read() throws MyReadException {
    byte[] data;

    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(this.file_path);
        int iv_size = input.read();
        byte[] iv = new byte[iv_size];
        input.read(iv);
        int encrypted_byte_size = input.read();
        byte[] data_encrypted = new byte[encrypted_byte_size];
        input.read(data_encrypted);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.getKey(), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        data = cipher.doFinal(data_encrypted);
        input.close();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException |
             IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | KeyStoreException |
             InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | UnrecoverableEntryException |
             CertificateException e) {
        throw new MyReadException(e);
    }

    return data;
}

public void write(byte[] data) throws MyWriteException {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.getKey());

        byte[] config_encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(this.file_path);
        stream.write(cipher.getIV().length);
        stream.write(cipher.getIV());
        stream.write(config_encrypted.length);
        stream.write(config_encrypted);
        stream.close();
    } catch (BadPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException |
             NoSuchPaddingException | KeyStoreException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException |
             UnrecoverableEntryException | IllegalBlockSizeException | CertificateException e) {
        throw new MyWriteException(e);
    }
}

private Key getKey() throws UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, CertificateException, IOException {
    KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    store.load(null);
    Key key = store.getKey(key_alias, null);
    if(key == null) {
        KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
        generator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                key_alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true).build());
        return generator.generateKey();
    }
    return key;
}
```